# Octave: Findfiles gives error

Tags: octave

I am trying to use the findfiles command in Octave:

names= findfiles('c:\users\user1\desktop')

which now returns: 
'findfiles' undefined near line 16 column 7

although the first time I ran it, it told me it was undefined at line 9 column 5.

I assume it's referring to the findfiles code(?).

Am I doing something dumb?  Does this code work?

I'm trying to run this on Windows 7.  I've already tried adding the path using addpath.

Comment: what is `findfiles` supposed to do anyway? It doesn't seem to be a missing Matlab function at least and it's also not any recently removed Octave function.

Comment: I'm trying to get the names of all the files in a directory so I can open them.  What other function would work for this?

Comment: there are many functions for that, depending on exactly what you want to do. `readdir` is the simplest, gives all files in specific directory. I will add an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

`findfiles` is invalid command in GNU Octave 3.8. You can achieve the same effect with other built-in functions or try the [unmaintained](http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php#unmaintained) [multicore](http://octave.sourceforge.net/multicore/overview.html) package.

Comment: Thanks.  That's good to know.  What function would you suggest I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

The function `findfiles` is very much non-standard. I'd recommend you use `readdir` instead.

```
[list_of_files] = readdir (path_to_directory)
```

This will give you a list of all files in a specific directory including directories (they are a type of file), and the special files `.` and `..`.

An alternative is to use `glob` which allows to filter them. For example:

```
[list_of_files] = glob ([path_to_directory "*.tar.gz"])
```

This will return all tar.gz files in a specific directory.

Other alternatives include `dir` and `ls`. The first returns a struct which may be handy if you want more info about the files, while the second is only useful for viewing at the command prompt (it runs the ls in the system and returns the output as string).